# lisp last element from every sublist odd

Tags: lisp

I want to find the number of sublists of any level for which the last numeric atom (at any level) is odd.
For example for:

```
 '(A (B 2) (1 C 4) (D 1(9 F)) ((G 7) 6))
```

The answer should be 3.(D 1 (9 F)),(9 F),(G 7).

My code:

```
(DEFUN numara (l)
  (COND  
   ((atom l) 0)
   ((verif l) (+ 1 (apply '+ (mapcar #'numara l))))
   (t (apply '+ (mapcar #'numara l)))
  )
 )

(DEFUN transform(l)
  (COND
   ((null l) nil)
   ((numberp (car l)) (cons (car l) (transform (cdr l))))
   ((atom (car l)) (transform (cdr l)))
   (t (append (transform (car l)) (transform (cdr l))))
  ) 
)

(DEFUN verif (l)
  (COND
  ((null (transform l)) nil)
  ((= 1(mod (reverse (transform l)) 2)) t)
  (t nil)
 )
)
```

The problem is in verif function. If I execute

```
numara '(A (B 2) (1 C 4) (D 1(9 F)) ((G 7) 6))
```

it gives me an error and it says:

```
 Cannot take car of 1.
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to solve the problem would be like this:

```
(defun last-numeric (list)
  "Return the last numeric element of a list."
  (find-if #'numberp list :from-end t))

(defun count-odd-last-numbers (list)
  "Recursively count all lists where the last numeric element is odd."
  (if (listp list)
    (let ((l-num (last-numeric list)))
      (+ (if (and l-num (oddp l-num))
             1 0)
         (loop for el in list
           sum (count-odd-last-numbers el))))
    0))
```

`last-numeric` uses `find-if` to find the last element of a list that satisfies the given predicate, `#'numberp`. `count-odd-last-numbers` will check if the argument is a list; if not return 0; if yes check if `last-numeric` returns an odd number, and loop over all elements recursively calling itself on them and summing the results.

As general advice to you, you shouldn't have the ending parentheses on seperate lines in Lisp code. Also you should try to come up with somewhat more descriptive, english, names for your functions and variables when posting code for others to see. In Lisp, you can also include a string as the first thing in a function body (see my functions); that is a docstring, which should explain the purpose of the function. You can see the docstring of a function with `(describe #'last-numeric)`, or by using your development environment to view it (`slime-describe-function` for example).